# Substitute part of text file using bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a shell script (bash) to fetch and build several bits of software. The script also writes several small config files and needs to alter a couple of pre-existing config files. What is the best way to find and substitute a few lines of a text file from a bash script?

This sounds like a job for `sed`, but I don't understand the syntax...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk/sed/bash/Python/Perl/Ruby and most other tools/programming languages all can do manipulation of files. The "best" way is the way you are familiar and comfortable with. If you don't know anything about sed, look it up and learn about it. Otherwise, if you have a  programming language you know, just do with it. Here's a bash script example

```
exec 6<"file"
while read -r line <&6
do
  case "$line" in 
    *pattern* )
       line="${line//word/replace}"
  esac
  echo "$line"
done > "out"
exec 6<&-
mv out file
```

sed example

```
sed 's/word/replace/g' file
```

awk example

```
awk '{gsub(/word/,"replace")}1' file > t && mv t file
```

Python example (use 'with' for later versions)

```
for line in open("file"):
    if "pattern" in line:
        line=line.replace("pattern","replace")
    print line
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but: http://catb.org/esr/writings/unix-koans/shell-tools.html

Comment: "When you are hungry, eat; when you are thirsty, drink; when you are tired, sleep." is sound advice but I have no food, water, or bed...

Answer (score 1):

`sed s/@var@/$VALUE/g <config.in >config`, but beware of stray slashes `/` in `$VALUE` -- you might need to escape them or use another separator char.